# Don't make edit history button selectable on iOS

Tags: bug, ios-app

On the Stack Exchange iOS app, I sometimes find it hard to access the edit history of a post by clicking "Edited xyz". It usually just selects the "Edited xyz" text and brings up the "Copy", "Look Up", and "Share" menu. It then takes me many tries to actually click and for it to work. Can we make the text non-selectable?

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)